# How are JSON files stored as B-Trees in NoSQL database?

Tags: json, nosql, b-tree

There are plenty of resources out there for me to find out how tables are stored as B-Trees in a relational database. I however cannot seem to find resources on how you would store JSON documents in a NoSQL database (I am thinking document oriented). Do any of you know how JSON files are stored as B-Trees in a document oriented NoSQL database?

Comment: Find an open source NoSQL database and study the code.

Comment: @boneill is this really the only way to learn? Has no one bothered to document how these things are implemented outside of source code? I highly doubt that. I just don't know where to find it.